# How extensive is the US Govt machine readable dataset on covid-19

Tags: covid-19, health-informatics, healthcare-data, covid-19-datasets

How extensive is the US Govt machine readable dataset on covid-19 and where can I find this data?

Comment: Unfortunately a question that asks for off site resources is considered off topic on SE so that's why I asked it like I did.  Now it's off topic!  :(

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a question that asks for off-site resources is off topic? We allow questions like that almost daily as long as they meet the other requirements such as prior research, which yours clearly does.

Comment: I've been under that impression for years https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic and knew nothing about community wiki :(

Comment: Big misunderstanding, Graham. That's stackoverflow, a completely different site with almost nothing in common with MedSci. We don't merely welcome off-site resources here, we demand them to support both questions and answers. Asking for data sources and providing them? Absolutely welcome.

Comment: No, I am sure it's the same here.  We provide references here to support answers but we don't normally provide link answers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296314/where-would-i-ask-about-a-specific-game-databases-existence/296316#296316 but I guess it's moot now

Comment: I don't give a crap about that post. It has no relevance to this site. Links to external databases are welcome here as long as they're reputable. I'm not going to spend my time finding the many examples of them that have been posted here but I assure you there's no such rule here.

Comment: Ok. I don't think I've been here since the site name and purpose changed

Answer (score 1):

[***I am answering this by copying Graham Chiu's words verbatim from his original, unedited question.***]

Original link: https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/call-action-tech-community-new-machine-readable-covid-19-dataset/

Link as of 14 September 2021: https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/briefings-statements/call-action-tech-community-new-machine-readable-covid-19-dataset/

> Today, researchers and leaders from the Allen Institute for AI, Chan Zuckerberg Initiative (CZI), Georgetown University’s Center for Security and Emerging Technology (CSET), Microsoft, and the National Library of Medicine (NLM) at the National Institutes of Health released the COVID-19 Open Research Dataset (CORD-19) of scholarly literature about COVID-19, SARS-CoV-2, and the Coronavirus group.
>
> Requested by The White House Office of Science and Technology Policy, the dataset represents the most extensive machine-readable Coronavirus literature collection available for data and text mining to date, with over 29,000 articles, more than 13,000 of which have full text.
>
> Now, The White House joins these institutions in issuing a call to action to the Nation’s artificial intelligence experts to develop new text and data mining techniques that can help the science community answer high-priority scientific questions related to COVID-19.
>
> The collection was constructed via a unique collaboration between Microsoft, NLM, CZI, and the Allen Institute for AI, coordinated by Georgetown University. Microsoft’s web-scale literature curation tools were used to identify and bring together worldwide scientific efforts and results, CZI provided access to pre-publication content, NLM provided access to literature content, and the Allen AI team transformed the content into machine-readable form, making the corpus ready for analysis and study.
>
> The CORD-19 resource is available on the Allen Institute’s SemanticScholar.org website and will continue to be updated as new research is published in archival services and peer-reviewed publications. Researchers should submit the text and data mining tools and insights they develop in response to this call to action via the Kaggle platform. Through Kaggle, a machine learning and data science community owned by Google Cloud, these tools will be openly available for researchers around the world.

The CORD-19 resource is available on the Allen Institute’s [SemanticScholar.org website](https://SemanticScholar.org)

Comment: You could make this Community Wiki if you want to avoid getting rep for it.

Comment: @BryanKrause *forehead slap*

Comment: Can you please update the link, 404 page not found

Comment: @AlexNolasco Done.